# How to search stored json object array string for multiple ids?

Tags: c#, json, linq-to-sql

In my database I have a table of records with a column that stores a JSON formatted string, that is a list of objects, with Id and other properties.
E.g.

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Item 1",
    "property 1": "foo",
    "property 2": "bar"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Item 2",
    "property 1": "foo2",
    "property 2": "bar2"
  }
]
```

From a third-party api call I obtain a list of Ids of the JSON objects.

**I wish to construct a Linq-to-SQL query** (ideally in dot notation/lamba syntax) **that will return all db records that have within their JSON string any of the IDs obtained from the api call.** This is just one clause out of many that I am having to construct dynamically for a larger query.

I am already achieving this outside of Linq-to-SQL by returning all db records, converting the JSON strings to arrays of objects and then filtering against those. (Code below) However, I want to reduce the load on the db and avoid having to return all the db records.

```
List<int> ids = GetIdsFromAPI();
var records = db.Records.Where(w => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(w.JSONString)).ToList();
List<int> recordIds = new List<int>();

foreach(var record in records)
{
    List<Item> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(record.JsonString);
    if(items.Any(a => ids.Contains(a.id)))
    {
        recordIds.Add(record.Id);
    }
}

largerQuery = largerQuery.Where(w => recordIds.Contains(w.Id));
```

Comment: I'm not a SQL Server developer, but maybe see [SQL LIKE query on JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57135701/3744182), https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017.

Comment: How many `ids` might there be?

Comment: There could be any number of ids. It is a dynamically generated list